# Random element selector in any language to embed in HTML

Tags: java, php, html, iframe, random

I am a novice at coding, and am looking for some help. What I need is a script in any language (Java, PHP, etc.) that:

1. Is embeddable in my HTML document.
2. Selects one item out of a set of objects.
3. These objects will be HTML iframes.

Basically what I am trying to do is have an iframe displayed, and when a user click the next/random button a different iframe will appear.

If you would like to help me even more, how would I arrange the iframes to be selected to the randomizer to choose?

Answer (score 0):

Put the URL to your iframes into a database, then select it using PHP, make sure to order it by `rand()`.

IE:

```
SELECT url FROM iframes ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1
```